# Take profit function of a timeseries

Tags: r

I am having great difficulty with this topic and I could use assistance from some experts. 
I have a standard time series, I can have it as an XTS or as a dataframe with numeric inputs. The headers are typical: DATE, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, SMA20, SMA50, CROSSOVER.

SMA20 refers to the 20 periods simple moving average. Crossover refers to where the 20 period SMA is above or below the SMA50. If its positive it is above, if it is negative it is below.

Here is my problem that I am trying to solve. How do I create a separate column to track profits or losses??? I want to create a take profit function at 100 pips and a stop loss function at 100 pips away from the entry point. The entry point will always be the open of the next day, once the crossover happens.

What I am thinking so far is to use the open price, then look at the difference of the high and the low for the day, if difference between the high and the open is greater than 100, the trade gets closed, if it is less, the trades stays open. I have no idea how to begin coding this.

Comment: The question is too general. Can you break it up into smaller questions and perhaps include some data?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: I've typed what I have tried. If you can help me by creating a basic take profit and stop loss code, I can maybe edit it myself to what I want.